# Shared preferences doesn't store int data

Tags: android, integer, sharedpreferences, textview, android-button

I have an activity with two TextViews which show int values. These values change incrementally (1, 2, 3, and so...) when the user clicks a button. I use `SharedPreferences` to store that values via button click. When I close the app and open it again, the values are correctly displayed in the TextViews, but if they change, they should be added from the previous stored value. Problem is that they start to count from zero.

Here is my code:

```
public class Roulette1 extends ActionBarActivity {

Button button0, button1;
int click_button0, click_button1;

public static final String button0Str = "button0Key";
public static final String button1Str = "button1Key";
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefsRoulette1";
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

TextView times_0_tv;
TextView times_1_tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout1);

    times_0_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.times_0);
    times_1_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.times_1);

    button0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button0);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    final TextView total_clicks_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total_clicks);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            click_button1 = click_button1 + 1;
            int total_clicks = click_button0 + click_button1;
            total_clicks_tv.setText(String.valueOf(total_clicks));

            times_0_tv.setText(click_button0);
            times_1_tv.setText(click_button1);

    button0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            click_button0 = click_button0 + 1;
            int total_clicks = click_button0 + click_button1;
            total_clicks_tv.setText(String.valueOf(total_clicks));

            times_0_tv.setText(click_button0);
            times_1_tv.setText(click_button1);

        }
    });

    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (sharedpreferences.contains(button0Str))
    {
        times_0_tv.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(button0Str, ""));
    }
    if (sharedpreferences.contains(button1Str))
    {
        times_1_tv.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(button1Str, ""));
    }
}

public void run1(View view) {

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

    String times0string = times_0_tv.getText().toString();
    String times1string = times_1_tv.getText().toString();
    editor.putString(button0Str, times0string);
    editor.putString(button1Str, times1string);

    editor.commit();
}
```

Hope you have any idea. Thanks!

Comment: `Problem is that they start to count from zero.`. Lucky guy. You are not even initialising them to zero. Or another value. You should get a compile time warning for that.

Comment: `Shared preferences doesn't store int data`. Wrong. You are trying to store Strings. Not ints.

Answer (score 2):

When you read from sharedPrefs, remember to update the field counters and not just the value of the textViews.

As suggested in the comments, a possible solution would be to use the textView value as the state, updating that directly. Otherwise you have to keep the counters updated manually, for example by updating the fields value at the same time you update the textView value. Personally, I prefer to keep the state separated from the presentation, so that it is easier to compute something with that value later (the downside is that you have to keep the view synchronized. This might change with [the new data binding library](https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html)).

PS I purposely did not put any code, because the solution is trivial and there are other answers with code, but more importantly because I think that the data binding library is a much cleaner way to deal with this kind of problems, even though it's still in beta stage.

Comment: This is the correct answer, the int counter variables are never initialized with the data from the shared preferences: click_button0 and click_button1. You really should elaborate on your answer though.

Comment: The best would be to do away with them. Then just read the old value from the textview at incrementing.

Answer (score 0):

Sharedpreferences stored int data also. Check this link:
http://androidexample.com/Android_SharedPreferences_Basics/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=126&aaid=146

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE); 
    Editor editor = pref.edit();


/**************** Storing data as KEY/VALUE pair *******************/

    editor.putBoolean("key_name1", true);           // Saving boolean - true/false
    editor.putInt("key_name2", "int value");        // Saving integer
    editor.putFloat("key_name3", "float value");    // Saving float
    editor.putLong("key_name4", "long value");      // Saving long
    editor.putString("key_name5", "string value");  // Saving string

    // Save the changes in SharedPreferences
    editor.commit(); // commit changes
```

I think there is some logical mistake in your code. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to the very beginning of your oncreate:

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

times0string = String.valueOf(sharedPreferences.getString(button0Str, 0));
times1string = String.valueOf(sharedPreferences.getString(button1Str, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, Try below code:

Replace first two line inside `button1 onClick()`

```
click_button1 = Integer.parseInt(sharedpreferences.getString(button1Str, "")) + 1;
int total_clicks = Integer.parseInt(sharedpreferences.getString(button0Str, "")) + click_button1;
```

Replace first two line inside `button0 onClick()`

```
click_button0 = Integer.parseInt(sharedpreferences.getString(button0Str, "")) + 1;
int total_clicks = click_button0 + Integer.parseInt(sharedpreferences.getString(button1Str, ""));
```